# Compute min/max position of tile in compute shader

Tags: shaders

I'm trying to implement tiled deferred lighting with OpenGL compute shaders. 
For that, I need to compute the minimum and maximum position of each tile.

My first approach was to use atomicCounters for the computation, like that:

```
shared int minX;
shared int minY;
shared int minZ;
shared int maxX;
shared int maxY;
shared int maxZ;
...
atomicMin(minX, positionWorld.x);
atomicMax(minY, positionWorld.y);
barrier();

// now the shared variables contain the min/max
// position per tile
```

But that runs painfully slow (I guess because the atomic operations aren't very well for  parallel processing).

**So what would be the best / fastest way to do this?**

Comment: use groupshared instead. they have some atomic adds you can use, and atmoic operations are quite fast in groupsthreads, but in systemthreads they are slower.

Comment: I cannot use groupshared, as I'm using openGL compute shaders (not OpenCL) .. but I guess shared already means groupshared for OpenGL compute shaders?